# Mysql query for get data from multiple columns to selected data by latest time

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, ajax

I have multiple columns in my DB but when I insert data in different columns I want to retrieve the data of the column which I have insert data now and other data retrieving should not be affected.

`SELECT h1 FROM latestnews ORDER BY h1 DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to modify a table row and want to see what exactly you've changed? Your question is not quite clear to understand. Maybe provide an example?

Comment: what problem you have faced with it?/

Comment: Please provide more details..

Comment: Where are your php, html, css and ajax problems?

Comment: i want to access last inserted data from many columns as specified column

Comment: in sql Mr. Huelfe

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a way of keeping track of changes to your table - in which case a trigger to insert changes to another table might be what you need.

Comment: exactly Mr. P.Salmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this table

```
drop table if exists mylog;
create table mylog 
(id int auto_increment primary key, dt date, tbl varchar(100),fld varchar(100), newvalue varchar(100));
```

and this table

```
CREATE TABLE `bank_trtypes` (
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Version` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `launchdate` date NOT NULL,
  `cde` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `LongName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `crdr` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'C=credit,D=Debit,N=Note',
  `CrLedgerCde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRLedgerCde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pbk` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'y=print to passbook',
  `stmt` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'y=print to stmt'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This trigger

```
drop trigger if exists `t_bank_trtypes_update`;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `t_bank_trtypes_update` after UPDATE ON `bank_trtypes` FOR EACH ROW begin

    if new.launchdate <> old.launchdate then    insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values (now(),'bank_trtypes','launchdate',new.launchdate); end if;
    if new.cde <> old.cde then insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values (now(),'bank_trtypes','cde',new.cde); end if;
    if new.longname <> old.longname then    insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values (now(),'bank_trtypes','longname',new.longname); end if;
    if new.crledgercde <> old.crledgercde then  insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values (now(),'bank_trtypes','crledgercde',new.crledgercde); end if;
    if new.drledgercde <> old.drledgercde then  insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values (now(),'bank_trtypes','drledgercde',new.drledgercde); end if;
    if new.pbk <> old.pbk then  insert into mylog (dt , tbl,fld , newvalue) values  (now(),'bank_trtypes','pbk',new.pbk); end if;

end //

delimiter ;
```

Will generate (1 or more) entries into mylog on an update
like so

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from bank_trtypes;
+------+---------+------------+-----+----------+------+-------------+-------------+-----+------+
| ID   | Version | launchdate | cde | LongName | crdr | CrLedgerCde | DRLedgerCde | pbk | stmt |
+------+---------+------------+-----+----------+------+-------------+-------------+-----+------+
|    1 |    2.00 | 2016-01-01 | so  | Stand    | d    |        NULL |        NULL | y   | y    |
+------+---------+------------+-----+----------+------+-------------+-------------+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from mylog;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update bank_trtypes set pbk = 'n' where 1 = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from mylog;
+----+------------+--------------+------+----------+
| id | dt         | tbl          | fld  | newvalue |
+----+------------+--------------+------+----------+
|  1 | 2016-11-28 | bank_trtypes | pbk  | n        |
+----+------------+--------------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Try googling for MYSQL update trigger for more examples.